# Roslyn CSharpCompilation.Create fails when passed CompilationUnit.SyntaxTree

Tags: roslyn

I have stumped on this problem and I am surely missing something. I have managed to wean the problem down to a reproductible sample that can be posted here.

This bit of sample code using the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxFactory

```
var compilationUnit = CompilationUnit()
.AddMembers(
    NamespaceDeclaration(ParseName("TopNSpace"))
        .AddMembers(
            InterfaceDeclaration("IInterfaceUsing")
                .AddModifiers(Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
                .AddMembers(
                    PropertyDeclaration(IdentifierName("ChildNSpace.IInterfaceUsed"), "UsingProperty")
                        .AddAccessorListAccessors(
                            AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration)
                                .WithSemicolonToken(Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken))
                            )
                )
            )
        )
.AddMembers(
    NamespaceDeclaration(ParseName("TopNSpace.ChildNSpace"))
        .AddMembers(
            InterfaceDeclaration("IInterfaceUsed")
                .AddModifiers(Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))
        )
    );
```

creates a CompilationUnitSyntax that yields this when calling NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString():

```
namespace TopNSpace
{
    public interface IInterfaceUsing
    {
        ChildNSpace.IInterfaceUsed UsingProperty { get; }
    }
}

namespace TopNSpace.ChildNSpace
{
    public interface IInterfaceUsed
    {
    }
}
```

My problem is that when I try to create a CSharpCompilation directly from the SyntaxTree of this CompilationUint, it yields an error:

```
var compilationFailed = CSharpCompilation.Create("Fails")
    .AddSyntaxTrees(compilationUnit.SyntaxTree) // Using SyntaxTree directly
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
```

The above yields this diagnostics error:
*The type or namespace name 'ChildNSpace.IInterfaceUsed' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

But if I parse the ToString() of the CompilationUnit to create a new Syntax Tree, it works:

```
var tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(compilationUnit.NormalizeWhitespace().ToFullString());

var compilationSucceeded = CSharpCompilation.Create("Succeeds")
    .AddSyntaxTrees(tree) // Now from the re-parsed string
    .WithOptions(new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary));
```

This works fine and yields no errors.

In both cases, the LanguageVersion of the CSharpCompilation is CSharp11.

What am I missing here? Shouldn't I be able to create a CSharpCompilation directly from the syntax tree?

In my real use-case, the syntax tree of the CompilationUnit is quite big and there is a significant performance hit when parsing a new tree from the CompilationUnit.ToString(). So I would really like to avoid it.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

thank you StackOverflow for being the rubber duck! Figured it out just after posting the question.

IdentifierName is no good when specifying a dotted type for a PropertyDeclationSyntax. It is the QualifiedNameSyntax that fits the bill.

Changing the type of the PropertyDeclaration from:

```
PropertyDeclaration(IdentifierName("ChildNSpace.IInterfaceUsed")
```

to:

```
PropertyDeclaration(QualifiedName(
        IdentifierName("ChildNSpace"),
        IdentifierName("IInterfaceUsed")
        )
```

fixed it!

Yeah, I feel stupid! I would say in my defense that when inspecting the generated code from ToString() it look exactly the same.

Live and learn!